# Как скопировать ключ реестра?

Tags: golang, реестр

Могу ли я скопировать ключ реестра, если да то как?

Читал офф документацию - *https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/windows/registry*, ничего подобного не нашел, неужто нужно самому принудительно создавать `key.reg` и записывать полученные данные с реестра?

UP: Ключ должен быть на выходе ввиде .reg файла

Comment: Для чего нужно копировать, т к скопировать можно копи пастом. Но вопрос в другом...в каком виде он вам нужен на выходе?

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц обновил вопрос, на выходе должен быть .reg

Comment: С помощью данного пакета - никак. Следует использовать Windows API, например функцию [RegSaveKeyA](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winreg/nf-winreg-regsavekeya).

Comment: Для экспорта ключа реестра вовсе необязательно лезть в дебри WinAPI, можно воспользоваться пакетом ```os/exec``` и вызвать ```reg export```. Например, наша команда с параметрами выглядит так: ```chunks := strings.Split("reg export hkcu\\software\\mykey mykey.reg /y", " ")```, первый элемент массива - reg.exe, который нужно вызвать ```exe := chunks[0]```, остальное - параметры ```par := chunks[1:len(chunks)]``` . Далее формируем команду ```cmd := exec.Command(exe, par...)``` и выполняем ее ```cmd.Run()```. При необходимости можно добавить плюшки вроде захвата stdout и stderr .